# How to Divide One Vector by Another

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, orthogonality

I have the following question and solution and I don't understand how to get from
$$ \frac{[1,1,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]}{[−1,−2,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]} $$
to
$$-\frac{2}{6}$$

Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks!

**Let $ℓ$ be the line through the origin that contains $[−1,−2,−1]$.**

**What is the image of $[1,1,−1]$ under the orthogonal projection $P_ℓ$?**

**The image of $[1,1,−1]$ under $P_ℓ$ can be calculated as follows:**

**$$P_ℓ([1,1,−1]) = \frac{[1,1,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]}{[−1,−2,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]}⋅[−1,−2,−1]$$**

**$$ =-\frac{2}{6}⋅[−1,−2,−1]$$**
**$$ =[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}] $$**

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with the dot product of vectors, which is a scalar?

Comment: don't confuse two concepts (you are also using improperly the same symbol  $\cdot$ for both): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication

Comment: You cannot divide a vector by another. Just because the dot product uses the same symbol as the multiplication of real numbers does not mean it is subject to the same rules. Look up "vector space".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get from  $ \dfrac{[1,1,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]}{[−1,−2,−1]⋅[−1,−2,−1]} $
to
$-\dfrac{2}{6}$ using the dot product.

The [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors $[a,b,c]$ and $[d,e,f]$, denoted $[a,b,c]\cdot[d,e,f]$,

is a scalar $ad+be+cf$.

Thus $[1,1,-1]\cdot[-1,-2,-1]=-1-2+1=-2$,

and $[-1,-2,-1]\cdot[-1,-2,-1]=1^2+2^2+1^2=6$.

Dot products are useful for computing lengths and angles.